# Toggle nav bar is not showing the list elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >

  $(".overlay").hover(
    function() {
      $(".overlay-desc").toggleClass("on");
    });


<
/script>


<
script >
  $("#nav a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".toggle").hide();
    var toShow = $(this).attr('href');
    $(toShow).show();
  });

<
/script>
```

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
}

.pad-lefrighp .col-sm-12,
.pad-lefrighp .col-xs-12,
.pad-lefrighp .col-md-4 {
  margin: 0;
}

.myclients .pad-lefrighp {
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin-bottom: 150px;
  margin-top: -200px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 100px) {
  .myclients .client_img {
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
  }
}

.myclients .margbottom {
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.myclients .innercontant .postboxa {
  background: #fbfbfb;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
  max-height: 420px;
}

.myclients .innercontant .postbox .postimage {
  height: 120px;
}

.myclients a {
  color: red;
}

.myclients ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  width: 1300px;
}

.myclients li {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 0px;
}

.myclients ul li a {
  padding: 0px 12px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 8px !important;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #D01A1A;
}

.myclients #all {
  font-family: Times New Roman;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.myclients .innercontant .postbox h6 {
  font-size: 13px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.myclients .wordwrptext {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  color: #424244;
}

.myclients .innercontant .btnn {
  margin-top: 15px;
  background: #fbad3f;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #fff;
}

.myclients .f-right {
  float: right;
}

.myclients .btn-sm,
.btn-group-sm>.btn {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.myclients a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.myclients a {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.myclients .postimage {
  margin-left: -12px;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.myclients .content {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 150px;
}

.myclients .col1 {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.myclients .col2 {
  float: right;
}

.myclients .bg {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 450px;
  height: 320px;
  background-size: 450px 320px;
}

.myclients .bg2 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 450px;
  height: 320px;
  background-size: 450px 320px;
}

.myclients .box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 450px;
  height: 320px;
  transition: all ease-in 0.3s;
}

.myclients .box:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.myclients .box:hover .image-caption {
  margin-top: -320px;
  background-color: rgba(208, 26, 26, 0.46);
  height: 68%;
}

.myclients .image-caption {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 430px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  margin-top: -69px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  transition: all ease-in 0.3s;
  margin-left: 0px;
}

.myclients .desc {
  position: absolute;
  width: 450px;
  margin-top: -200px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Georgia, serif;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.4;
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  transition: all ease-in 0.3s;
  margin-left: 0px;
}

.myclients .see-more {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.legend {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Helvetica, Aria, sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: rgb(192, 192, 192);
}

.myclients .on {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.myclients .navv a {
  border: 1px solid #D01A1A;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  margin: 0 8px !important;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.myclients .navv a.selected {
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #D01A1A;
}

.myclients .navv a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #D01A1A;
}

a:active {
  outline: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 0;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 400px) and (max-width: 2000px) {
  width: 100%;
}

.myclients .navv {}

.img-fluid {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang=""> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang=""> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang=""> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class="no-js" lang="">
<!--<![endif]-->

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="description" content="">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>abcn</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/flexslider.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.fancybox.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsive.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-icon.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style4.css" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Great+Vibes" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.bootcss.com/animate.css/3.5.1/animate.min.css">






  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" type='text/css'>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>


  <!-- header section -->
  <section class="banner" role="banner" id="home">
    <header id="header" class="fixed">
      <div class="header-content clearfix">
        <a class="logo" href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.jpg" style="width: 180px; height: 100px" class="img-rounded"></a>
        <nav class="navigation" role="navigation">
          <ul class="primary-nav">
            <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="designs.php">designes</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="gal.php">New Arrivals</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <a href="#" class="nav-toggle">Menu<span></span></a> </div>
    </header>
  </section>


  <div class="myclients">
    <div class="container-fulid ">
      <div class="pad-lefrighp">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-md-4">
            <div class="content">
              <div class="col1">
                <div class="bg">

                  <a class="" href="admin/uploads/1.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="admin/uploads/1.jpg" class="img-fluid" /> <span class="image-caption">Price: <i class="fa fa-rupee" style="font-size:20px"></i>&nbsp; 500</span> </a>
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>





    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
    <script src="js/retina.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/modernizr.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.contact.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here, the navigation bar is working in PC. Coming to Mobiles navigation bar is not working. When I click on the nav menu icon it's just showing the same page. it's not showing the list elements like home, about us, designs etc. where the script is stopping, and also issue with mobile responsiveness Check it once. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to add document ready before your bind on the click take a look here : https://api.jquery.com/ready/ and add it too the hover bind

Comment: And i think you make mistake here ` $(".toggle").hide();` it's not ` $(".nav-toggle").hide();` ?

Comment: i am not getting. please explain detail